# What is the difference between the string and []byte in Go?

Tags: string, go, slice

```
s := "some string"
b := []byte(s) // convert string -> []byte
s2 := string(b) // convert []byte -> string
```

what is the difference between the `string` and `[]byte` in Go?

When to use "he" or "she"?

Why?

```
bb := []byte{'h','e','l','l','o',127}
ss := string(bb)
fmt.Println(ss)
```

> hello

The output is just `"hello"`, and lack of `127`, sometimes I feel that it's weird.

Comment: The character value [127 (ASCII DEL)](http://www.asciitable.com/) is *part* of the string. However it does not render as a character (here). Look at the length of the string (it will be 6) to verify this character *is* included, even if not shown. (A number of other characters codes, eg those below 32, will also not be rendered as characters in a standard console.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`string`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_types) and [`[]byte`](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) are different types, but [they can be converted to one another](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type):

> 3 . Converting a slice of bytes to a string type yields a string whose successive bytes are the elements of the slice.
>
> 4 . Converting a value of a string type to a slice of bytes type yields a slice whose successive elements are the bytes of the string.

Blog: [Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](https://blog.golang.org/slices):

> Strings are actually very simple: they are just read-only slices of bytes with a bit of extra syntactic support from the language.

Also read: [Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://blog.golang.org/strings)

**When to use one over the other?**

Depends on what you need. Strings are immutable, so they can be shared and you have guarantee they won't get modified.

Byte slices can be modified (meaning the content of the backing array).

Also if you need to frequently convert a `string` to a `[]byte` (e.g. because you need to write it into an [`io.Writer()`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer)), you should consider storing it as a `[]byte` in the first place.

Also note that you can have `string` [constants](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) but there are no slice constants. This may be a small optimization. Also note that:

> The expression `len(s)` is constant if `s` is a string constant.

Also if you are using code already written (either standard library, 3rd party packages or your own), in most of the cases it is given what parameters and values you have to pass or are returned. E.g. if you read data from an [`io.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/io/#Reader), you need to have a `[]byte` which you have to pass to receive the read bytes, you can't use a `string` for that.

---

This example:

```
bb := []byte{'h','e','l','l','o',127}
```

What happens here is that you used a [composite literal](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) (slice literal) to create and initialize a new slice of type `[]byte` (using [Short variable declaration](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)). You specified constants to list the initial elements of the slice. You also used a byte value `127` which - depending on the platform / console - may or may not have a visual representation.

Answer (score 6):

Late but i hope this could help.

**In simple words**

- **Bit**: `0` and `1` is how machines represents all the information
- **Byte**: `8 bits` that represents UTF-8 encodings i.e. characters
- **[ ]type**: slice of a given data type. Slices are dynamic size arrays.
- **[ ]byte**: this is a byte slice i.e. a `dynamic` size array that contains bytes i.e. each element is a UTF-8 character.
- **String**: read-only slices of bytes i.e. `immutable`

---

With all this in mind:

```golang
s := "Go"
bs := []byte(s)
fmt.Printf("%s", bs)     // Output: Go
fmt.Printf("%d", bs)     // Output: [71 111]
```

or

```golang
bs := []byte{71, 111}
fmt.Printf("%s", bs)     // Output: Go
```

`%s` converts byte slice to string

`%d` gets UTF-8 decimal value of bytes

---

**IMPORTANT:**

As `strings are immutable`, they cannot be changed within memory, each time you add or remove something from a string, GO creates a new string in memory. On the other hand, `byte slices are mutable` so when you update a byte slice you are not recreating new stuffs in memory.

So choosing the right structure could make a difference in your app performance.

Comment: This answer is more understandable for ordinary humans.

Comment: `[ ]byte: this is a byte slice i.e. a dynamic size array that contains bytes i.e. each element is a UTF-8 character.` Are you sure about that ?