# Is string a reference type or a value type

Tags: string, go

I was recently reading the source code of go. I see that there is a file called `string.go` in the source code, but at the same time, the string is the predeclared identifiers, and it also being used in the source code directly?

I found some article that said `string` is the reference type. but I try to run the following code:

```
func TestString(t *testing.T) {
    s := "abc"

    fmt.Println("address of s: ", &s)

    xx := func(sss string) {
        fmt.Println("address of sss: ", &sss)
        sss = "123"
    }

    xx(s)

    fmt.Println("value of s after sss modified the content: ", s)
}

output: 
=== RUN   TestString
address of s:  0xc00010a560
address of sss:  0xc00010a570
value of s after sss modified the content:  abc
--- PASS: TestString (0.00s)
```

if the `string` is reference, So when I pass the `s` to `func(sss string)`, the address of `sss` should be the same with `s`, and `s` should be modified, but it wasn't, why?

Is the go did something of string, let it seems like a value type? but where is the code? if the `string` is a refernce type and the actual type of `string` is `type stringStruct`, it should be defined the behavior somewhere?

It really confuse me

Comment: There are *NO* true reference types in Go. There are only reference-*like* types. **Everything is pass-by-value.** A string is implemented using a header structure that points to the underlying data. So when you pass around a string you are copying the string-header. And this goes for every single data type in Go, **including pointers**, so when you pass an instance of `T` around you are creating copies of that instance.

Comment: As you said, when I pass around a string, the go copied the string-header, but there is a pointer field in this struct `Data uintptr`, if go just copied the `StringHeader`, So the value of `Data uintprt` should be the same(it means the same address value) . And I found that slice and so on are similarly implemented: struct type and a pointer field to the underlying data.

Comment: The value of `Data uintptr` is the same for both `s` and `sss`. But, as explained by icza, `&s` and `&sss` are addresses of the variables, i.e. the headers themselves, not the values of `Data uintptr`. See https://go.dev/play/p/nSxM4fOtXqc

Comment: @mkopriva I wrote some fake code to explain my understanding, See https://go.dev/play/p/ctYDwjh_A9Z. Is it right?

Comment: `sss.Data = newptr` is not equivalent to the original `sss = "123"`. Instead it should be `sss = Str{Data: newptr}`. Although given your example the result will be the same, the distinction is important.

Answer (score 4):

`&s` and `&sss` are the addresses of variables. Since they are 2 distinct non-zero size variables, their addresses must be different, which you experience.

There are no reference types in Go in the classic C sense. A `string` is a small struct-like value described by [`reflect.StringHeader`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StringHeader):

```
type StringHeader struct {
    Data uintptr
    Len  int
}
```

It contains a pointer where the UTF-8 encoded bytes of the string are stored, and a byte-length.

When you assign something to a variable of `string` type, you change the value of the variable (the above small `StringHeader` struct), but not the pointed data. When you assign something to the `sss` variable, the original `s` variable is unchanged, it still contains the same data pointer pointing to the same bytes.

Read [The Go Blog: Strings, bytes, runes and characters in Go](https://go.dev/blog/strings)

See related questions:

[Immutable string and pointer address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47352449/immutable-string-and-pointer-address/47352588#47352588)

[What is the difference between the string and []byte in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625959/what-is-the-difference-between-the-string-and-byte-in-go/32626057#32626057)

Comment: On a technicality, there is no guarantee that the bytes of a string are UTF-8 encoded, is there?  (I understood it to be more likely than not, but not guaranteed).

Comment: @Deltics Go stores the UTF-8 encoded bytes of texts, but a `string` may hold arbitrary byte sequences, even invalid UTF-8 sequences too.

Answer (score 0):

I added couple of printlines to display `StringHeader.Data` value of `sss` after updation inside the function of @mkopriva's [code](https://go.dev/play/p/nSxM4fOtXqc) fore better understanding, which can found [here@ https://go.dev/play/p/Q83hcTlVLl8](https://go.dev/play/p/Q83hcTlVLl8).

```bash
# Output:
address of s:  0xc000014070
address of s.Data:  "4828225"
address of sss before modification:  0xc000014080
address of sss.Data before modification:  "4828225"
address of sss after modification:  0xc000014080
address of sss.Data after modification:  "4828333"
```

Value of `StringHeader.Data` is same for both `s` and `sss` until later is updated. Once `sss` updates, its `StringHeader.Data` is also changed. Hence this new value doesn't reflect in original `s`.